# How to Strip Specific Styles From Html Page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, regex

Application uses angularJs if that's relevant.

We allow the user to generate custom html and then show it in a preview window. For example, the user enters the following:

```
<div style = "background-color:red; border: 1px solid;">Hi there</div>
```

My goal, specifically, is to take this html (I get it as a string) and strip all border styles, so take above as an argument and return:

```
<div style = "background-color:red;">Hi there</div>
```

What's the best way to approach it? RegEx or is there some other solution. I have thought about ng-sanitize, but it seems like it would be a huge pain to even think about modifying it to do this.

Comment: Definitely don't use a regex. Just parse as HTML, visit every node removing the style tag, and serialize again.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Can you explain that a little bit more please? Specifically the "visit every node" part.

Comment: `function handleNode(node){node.stripAttr("style"); node.children.forEach(handleNode)}; handleNode(root)`

Comment: is it just the border that you want to remove or there can be more styles/rules?

Comment: @JanDvorak they only want to remove border, not all of style

Comment: I just want to remove the border style. If it helps, there are no class styles here, ever, just in-line.

Comment: @iismathwizard oh. Then just edit the attribute with a regex instead of removing it. CSS is well specced and should be possible to implement exactly.

Comment: @JanDvorak or don't use regex because that's wrong and just use `removeProperty` in javascript

Comment: true... That should work, too.

Comment: you can also override it using css see my answer

Comment: @NikhilBhandari: I have to strip borders from every html possible. Or, at the very least, for this particular question: divs tables, table cells, and table rows. Actually, your solution might work with the "!important" override, I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip all the border styles from any element by changing that element's

`.style.border`

to

`null`

For example:

```js
function stripBorderStyles() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i = 3; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].style.border = null;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load',stripBorderStyles,false);
```

```html
<h2>Before:</h2>
<div style = "background-color:red; border: 1px solid;">Hi there</div>
<div style = "background-color:red; border: 2px solid;">Hey there</div>
<div style = "background-color:red; border: 3px solid;">Howdy</div>

<h2>After:</h2>
<div style = "background-color:red; border: 1px solid;">Hi there</div>
<div style = "background-color:red; border: 2px solid;">Hey there</div>
<div style = "background-color:red; border: 3px solid;">Howdy</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, looking at this as well as a solution.

Comment: This is the answer that ended up being the most useful to me in getting it done, thank you.

Comment: @VSO i thought you said you had to get all elements, not just one specific type.

Comment: @iismathwizard I just looped through the element names that I needed to change the borders on. Honestly, I might have chosen this answer because I have never worked with nodes before, and with this one, I understood EXACTLY what I am doing. I will make a bounty when the timer expires, that way you guys can pick the best answer amongst yourselves. I think people will look at this q later. I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: @VSO oh i don't care which you picked for the accepted answer. I just didn't understand why this was picked with the requirements you gave. Thanks for explaining. No need for a bounty in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to use regex for this. Please don't even try as it's just not the right way.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = myHtmlString;

//recursively visit all nodes in div
//and remove border style elem.style.removeProperty('border');
```

To provide a little more context on this since I didn't really describe how to do the recursive border removal:

You create the div and set the string as `div.innerHTML` because it will allow you to perform DOM functions on them making it easier to manipulate the styles. A potential solution to visit all nodes is below. I chose to not write it recursively because I personally don't like recursion.

```js
function load()
{   
var contents = "<div style=\"border: 1px solid red; color: blue;\"><div style=\"border: 1px solid red; color: blue;\">test1</div><div style=\"border: 1px solid red; color: blue;\"><div style=\"border: 1px solid red; color: blue;\">test2</div><div style=\"border: 1px solid red; color: blue;\">test3</div></div><div style=\"border: 1px solid red; color: blue;\">test4</div></div>";

//before removing border
var beforeDiv = document.createElement('div');
beforeDiv.innerHTML = contents;
document.body.appendChild(beforeDiv);

//after removing border
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = contents;

//list of all nodes to visit
var nodesToVisit = new Array();

//load each child of div into this list
for(i = 0; i < div.children.length; i ++)
{
 nodesToVisit.push(div.children[i]);
}

//process entire list until we've exhausted all children
for(i = 0; i < nodesToVisit.length; i ++)
{
 var node = nodesToVisit[i];
 
 if(node != undefined)
 {    
  if(node.style != undefined)
  {
   //remove property of border
   node.style.removeProperty("border");
  }
  
  //add each child of node to list for processing. effectively recursive
  for(j = 0; j < node.children.length; j ++)
  {
   nodesToVisit.push(node.children[j]);
  }
 }
}

document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body onload="load()">
 </body>
</html>
```

This is just a demo page that dynamically loads in divs but this would work with all elements, not just divs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have never iterated through html nodes before, so figuring out how to do that. Will come back to accept answer once I figure it out.

Comment: The correct way to parse HTML is `DOMParser`. Just shoving it into a DIV is unsafe due to script tags, onevent attributes and such.

Comment: @JanDvorak how is it unsafe, exactly?

Comment: Let's say the parsed HTML contains a script tag. I'm not sure these get executed but i wouldn't risk it. Let's say the parsed HTML contains an image with an invalid URL and an onerror tag. The tag contents will get executed. Plus, the URL target may log an incoming GET request to a specific forged URL - or two (one to trigger the script, one to transmit the scraped off data). Let's say the HTML links to a CSS file / web audio file / video file... Sure, this time the parsing only happens on the attacker's own page, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: Hell, even wasting the victim's bandwidth by uploading gigabytes upon gigabytes of randomly generated data into a trash can can be fun... or downloading it from a fast PRNG to hog up bandwidth _and_ RAM (and you don't even need javascript to pull this off - just an image tag will do)

Comment: @JanDvorak it looks as if the user (the one viewing the page) is also the one writing the html so i don't see how these concerns are relevant. If the user wants to punish themselves with audio files, malicious script tags, broken links then i don't see why they shouldn't be able too

Comment: @VSO I've made an edit that might add clarity to my answer

Comment: @iismathwizard Thanks, I am still looking at all solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with css also

let's say you have a variable `html` in scope, and you bind it this way

```
<div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
```

just wrap it around a div with class `strip-borders`

```
<div class="strip-borders">
    <div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
</div>
```

and then add following class  to remove borders form div

```
.strip-borders div {
    border:none !important;
}
```

or remove borders from any element (use cautiously)

```
.strip-borders * {
    border:none !important;
}
```

See the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8vzq9j6p/

Answer (score -3):

you can do this with 
$.css("background-color", "");

Comment: @iismathwizard that's a relatively small problem with this answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak true but it's still a key one that Sagar obviously missed

Comment: Let me mention the other problems, if you don't mind. Removes (or tries to remove) the wrong property; isn't even correct jQuery - `css` is an instance property; doesn't handle the "parse as HTML", "visit every node" and "serialize" parts.